# How is GetHashCode() of F# record implemented?

Tags: hash, f#, record, hashcode

I'm struggling a bit to find it on https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

and this is very important because I need to ensure the least amount of collisions possible.

Comment: You can use a decompiler or place the cursor on the method or record, and hit `F12`. That method, along with `Equals` is generated by the compiler for each record type.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, that is good to know. Could you provide an example generated code for a typical record with a few properties of some different types?

Comment: You can see the code yourself with a decompiler, if not by hitting `F12` on the record. That's what I'll have to do to get that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As VoroniPotato mentions, you might want to override `GetHashCode` yourself, but the default implemention of `GetHashCode` works like the following for a record. Assuming `fields` is a list of the value of the fields in the record, then the following steps are done:

1. Start with an initial value of 0.
2. Then for each element in field, starting from the last one defined (i.e. given the record type `{a: int; b: string}` we start with `b`), do the following:

   `0x9e3779b9 + fields.[i].GetHashCode() + (value <<< 6) + (value >>> 2)`, where value is the value from the previous iteration of the algorithm. We assume `fields.[i]` isn't null, otherwise its hash value is just set to 0.
3. Repeat step 2 for all fields.

You can see this in the source code from the code for [mkRecdHashWithComparer](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/AugmentWithHashCompare.fs#L587)  and [mkAddToHashAcc](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/AugmentWithHashCompare.fs#L99).

For the simple example record of `{a: int; b: string}`, the decompiled `GetHashCode` method is this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
public sealed override int GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comp)
{
    if (this != null)
    {
        int num = 0;
        num = -1640531527 + ((b@?.GetHashCode() ?? 0) + ((num << 6) + (num >> 2)));
        return -1640531527 + (a@ + ((num << 6) + (num >> 2)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I can tell you it's not going to provide the least amount of collisions possible. You may want to override GetHashCode. Some have complained that it didn't fit their hashing needs but that for backwards compatiblity it couldn't reasonably be changed. I would add an issue on the github visual fsharp repository if this a serious issue for you due to performance considerations of checking conflicted hashes.

Update, Sources: 
[github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/366](http://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/366) 
[github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/343](http://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/343) 
[github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1838](http://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1838)

Comment: Could you please provide a source for this statement?